# Ext JS 4 Basic Grid Example Gets JSON Value

Tags: extjs4, javascript

Is there any simple example that takes data from a link that is a JSON array and shows it a basic grid table at Ext JS 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This simple example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html) loads json data into grid using ajax proxy.